# Fetching the value of forms in WordPress AJAX

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

I have a form with AJAX Submit. I am getting the value of fields as null.

```
jQuery('#DownloadForm').submit(ajaxSubmit);

 function ajaxSubmit() {
    var DownloadForm = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
      type:    "POST",
      url:     aj_ajax_demo.ajax_url,
       data : {
                action : 'set_lead_cookie_and_mail',  // Note that this is part of the add_action() call.
                nonce : aj_ajax_demo.aj_demo_nonce,  // Note that 'aj_demo_nonce' is from the wp_localize_script() call.
                form_data : DownloadForm
            },
      success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);

      }
    });
    return false;
  }
```

And this is how I am fetching the data.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_set_lead_cookie_and_mail', 'mail_and_cookie_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_set_lead_cookie_and_mail', 'mail_and_cookie_function' ); 

function mail_and_cookie_function() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'aj-demo-nonce', 'nonce' );  // This function will die if nonce is not correct.

    $name =  sanitize_text_field($_POST["wpcf-lead-name"]);
    $email =  sanitize_text_field($_POST["wpcf-lead-email"]);
    $number =  sanitize_text_field($_POST["wpcf-lead-number"]);
    $class =  $_POST["wpcf-class"];
    $category =  sanitize_text_field($_POST["hidden_category"]);

    if(!$_COOKIE[$category]) {      
        setcookie($category, "1", time()+2592000);
        wp_send_json($class);
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

My response header is sending all the data correctly.

I am getting null as the response. I expect to get the value of the forms submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer to the question. 
Using `parse_str($_POST['form_data'], $form_data);` in my function allows me to call all the field values as `$name =  $form_data["wpcf-lead-name"];`

Now my new function looks like this.

```
function mail_and_cookie_function() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'aj-demo-nonce', 'nonce' );  
    parse_str($_POST['form_data'], $form_data); // This is the new added line
    $name =  $form_data["wpcf-lead-name"];  // This is how you call the field.
    $email =  $form_data['wpcf-lead-email'];
    $number = $form_data["wpcf-lead-number"];
    $class =  $form_data["wpcf-class"];
    $category =  $form_data["hidden_category"];

    if(!$_COOKIE[$category]) {      
        setcookie($category, "1", time()+2592000);
        wp_send_json("redirecting");
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should rename your function to `set_lead_cookie_and_mail` and change it in the `add_action()` as well. 
It looks like your action `set_lead_cookie_and_mail` in your ajax call is never reached, does it even exist?

Comment: Yes,it reaches the action function. Read Ajax on the Viewer-Facing Side here (https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)